# How can I Transform object in objects to array with es6 or lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I try to doing this object

```
obj={ 
    a:{ 1:"x", 2:"c"}, 
    b:{ 1:"v", 2:"b" }, 
    c:{ 4:"n", 2:"k" } 
}
```

to

```
 obj=[
    0:{group:"a" ,1:"x"},
    1:{group:"a", 2:"c"},
    2:{group:"b",1:"v"},
    3:...]
```

Comment: Your `to` object is confusing.  You suggest you want an array, but that is not the proper syntax.  It uses square brackets like an array, but key/val pairs like an object.  One suggestion may be to be more explicit/correct in what your desired value will be

Comment: I absolutely know it's a not a free coding service. My code tries goes nothing. So I just write that what i have and what i expect. I know to rules but it's my first and last time to stretch the rules :)

Comment: @Ryoush it’s not about rules. It’s just decency.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Overreact? Just take it easy champ.

Comment: @Ryoush No worries, I’m calm. It’s always good to know where someone got to themselves. It certainly makes it easier to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object into an array. Use `.reduce()`, `.concat()` and `map()` to construct the new array

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    1: "x",
    2: "c"
  },
  b: {
    1: "v",
    2: "b"
  },
  c: {
    4: "n",
    2: "k"
  }
}


let result = Object.entries(obj)
                   .reduce((c, [k, v]) => c.concat(Object.entries(v).map(o => ({group: k,[o[0]]: o[1]}))), [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it's a great explanation.Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` to get all the keys from the object. Then use array `reduce` function & inside the callback function loop over the object and create a new object.

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    1: "x",
    2: "c"
  },
  b: {
    1: "v",
    2: "b"
  },
  c: {
    4: "n",
    2: "k"
  }
}
let m = Object.keys(obj);

let z = m.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (typeof(obj[curr]) === 'object') {
    for (let keys in obj[curr]) {
      let __ob = {};
      __ob.group = curr;
      __ob[keys] = obj[curr][keys]
      acc.push(__ob)
    }

  }
  return acc;

}, [])
console.log(z)
```

Comment: its a great explanation too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your keys at both levels and use computed keys syntax as provided by ES6/ES2015:

```js
let obj={ a:{ 1:"x", 2:"c"}, b:{ 1:"v", 2:"b" }, c:{ 4:"n", 2:"k" } }

let result = []
for (let k1 in obj){
  for (let k2 in obj[k1] ){
    result.push({group:k1,[k2]:obj[k1][k2]})
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash, iterate the the object with [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap). In the flatMap's callback, the 1st parameter is the value (`{ 1: 'x', 2: 'c' }` for example), and the 2nd parameter is the key (`a` for example). Assign the 2nd parameter to `group`. Use `_.toPairs()` to get an array of pairs (`[key, value]`). Convert the pairs to object with `Array.map()`, and include the `group`:

```js
const obj = {"a":{"1":"x","2":"c"},"b":{"1":"v","2":"b"},"c":{"2":"k","4":"n"}};

const result = _.flatMap(obj, 
  (o, group) => 
    _.toPairs(o).map(([k, v]) => ({
      group,
      [v]: k
    })));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Absolutely very happy to seeing lodash version too. Thank you so much